# Exception handling with Dire

Tags: exception, clojure

I'm trying to handle exceptions with [Dire](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire) library. Like this:

```
(defn test-fn []
  (client/head "https://google.com/404")
)

(with-handler! #'test-fn
           java.lang.Exception
          (fn [e] "error!"))
```

But always got an error:

> ExceptionInfo clj-http: status 404  clj-http.client/wrap-exceptions/fn--3052 (client.clj:196)

I've tried to change java.lang.Exception to clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo with same effect. Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried putting something you're sure doesn't error in test-fn? Something like `(defn test-fn [] (comment "I'm a banana"))` or `(defn test-fn [] (throw (Exception. "testing")))` . . . Both of which work for me with Dire 0.5.3

Comment: Could it be an arity issue. Perhaps you need `(fn [e & args] "error!")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clj-http uses [Slingshot](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot) apparently, cf. [clj-http documentation on exceptions](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#exceptions). The `throw+` operation of Slingshot can throw any kind of object, not just exceptions (`Throwable`s). The clj-http documentation has an example:

```
; Response map is thrown as exception obj.
; We filter out by status codes
(try+
  (client/get "http://some-site.com/broken")
  (catch [:status 403] {:keys [request-time headers body]}
    (log/warn "403" request-time headers))
  (catch [:status 404] {:keys [request-time headers body]}
    (log/warn "NOT Found 404" request-time headers body))
  (catch Object _
    (log/error (:throwable &throw-context) "unexpected error")
    (throw+)))
```

Furthermore, the [Dire documentation](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire#slingshot-integration) has an example of how to integrate with Slingshot: basically you should be able to drop `[:status 404]` instead of the `java.lang.Exception`.